# Problem with my instance's functions not working (Python3, Pygame), check my code?

Tags: python, class, pygame

Been trying to turn my main character into a class that I can call in my game. This is because I know it will get a lot more complex later in the development due to plans to implement enemies and spawn-able power-ups.

For some reason, my sprite will be drawn but the methods to get make it detect my key and then move (getkey, animandmove) don't seem to work as pressing any of the inputs does not move it. Please help?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import pyganim  # used for animations

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

WINDOWWIDTH = 1600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 900

# x = 100
# y = 100
# vel = 10
# width = 64
# height = 64
# moveleft = moveright = moveup = movedown = False
# direction = 'left'

background = pygame.image.load('sprites/background1.png')
leftidle = pygame.image.load("sprites/left.png")
rightidle = pygame.image.load("sprites/right.png")
upidle = pygame.image.load("sprites/up.png")
downidle = pygame.image.load("sprites/down.png")

charanim = {"walkleft": pyganim.PygAnimation(
[("sprites/left2.png", 100), ("sprites/left.png", 100), ("sprites/left3.png", 100), ("sprites/left.png", 10)]),
"walkright": pyganim.PygAnimation(
    [("sprites/right2.png", 100), ("sprites/right.png", 100), ("sprites/right3.png", 100),
     ("sprites/right.png", 10)]), "walkup": pyganim.PygAnimation(
    [("sprites/up2.png", 100), ("sprites/up.png", 100), ("sprites/up3.png", 100), ("sprites/up.png", 10)]),
"walkdown": pyganim.PygAnimation(
    [("sprites/down2.png", 100), ("sprites/down.png", 100), ("sprites/down3.png", 100), ("sprites/down.png", 10)])}
moveConductor = pyganim.PygConductor(charanim)

mainmenuanim = {"splashscreen": pyganim.PygAnimation([("sprites/splash1.png", 500), ("sprites/splash2.png", 500)])}
mainmenuConductor = pyganim.PygConductor(mainmenuanim)

muzzleflashanim = {"fire": pyganim.PygAnimation(
[("sprites/muzzleflash.png", 100), ("sprites/muzzleflash2.png", 100),                 ("sprites/muzzleflash3.png", 100),
 ("sprites/muzzleflash4.png", 100)])}

mainwin = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("2084 Ver 0.1.1.1")


def mainmenu():
global running
menulive = True
pygame.mixer.music.load('track0.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
while menulive:
    mainmenuConductor.play()
    mainmenuanim["splashscreen"].blit(mainwin, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RETURN:
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                mainloop()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.update()


def mainloop():
global running
running = True
char1 = Character()
pygame.mixer.music.load("track1.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
char1.__init__()
while running:
    mainwin.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    char1.getkey()
    char1.animandmove()
    pygame.display.update()


class Character:

def __init__(self):
    self.x = 100
    self.y = 100
    self.vel = 10
    self.width = 64
    self.height = 64
    self.moveleft = False
    self.moveright = False
    self.moveup = False
    self.movedown = False
    self.direction = 'left'

def animandmove(self):
    if self.moveleft or self.moveright or self.moveup or self.movedown:
        moveConductor.play()

        # draws animations for each of the directions
        if self.direction == "left":
            charanim["walkleft"].blit(mainwin, (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.direction == "right":
            charanim["walkright"].blit(mainwin, (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.direction == "up":
            charanim["walkup"].blit(mainwin, (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.direction == "down":
            charanim["walkdown"].blit(mainwin, (self.x, self.y))

        # moving the physicial character
        if self.moveleft and self.x > 0:
            self.x -= self.vel
        if self.moveright and self.x < (WINDOWWIDTH - 64):
            self.x += self.vel
        if self.moveup and self.y > 0:
            self.y -= self.vel
        if self.movedown and self.y < (WINDOWHEIGHT - 64):
            self.y += self.vel
    else:
        moveConductor.stop()
        if self.direction == "left":
            mainwin.blit(pygame.image.load("sprites/left.png"), (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.direction == "right":
            mainwin.blit(pygame.image.load("sprites/right.png"), (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.direction == "up":
            mainwin.blit(pygame.image.load("sprites/up.png"), (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.direction == "down":
            mainwin.blit(pygame.image.load("sprites/down.png"), (self.x, self.y))

def getkey(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                self.moveleft = True
                self.moveright = False
                if not self.moveup and not self.movedown:
                    self.direction = "left"
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                self.moveleft = False
                self.moveright = True
                if not self.moveup and not self.movedown:
                    self.direction = "right"
            elif event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                self.moveup = True
                self.movedown = False
                if not self.moveleft and not self.moveright:
                    self.direction = "up"
            elif event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                self.moveup = False
                self.movedown = True
                if not self.moveleft and not self.moveright:
                    self.direction = "down"
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                self.moveleft = False
                if self.moveup:
                    self.direction = "up"
                if self.movedown:
                    self.direction = "down"
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                self.moveright = False
                if self.moveup:
                    self.direction = "up"
                if self.movedown:
                    self.direction = "down"
            elif event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                self.moveup = False
                if self.moveleft:
                    self.direction = "left"
                if self.moveright:
                    self.direction = "right"
            elif event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                self.movedown = False
                if self.moveleft:
                    self.direction = "left"
                if self.moveright:
                    self.direction = "right"

        pygame.display.update()


mainmenu()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: In case you're wondering about the close and downvotes: please, format your code, and remove all clutter, assets and unnecessary stuff that's not relevant to your question. You have the best chances to get good answers if one can copy/paste your code and immediatly run it.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you have two event loops.

In your main loop, you call `pygame.event.get()` to get all events which will clear the event queue.

Later, you call `pygame.event.get()` again in `char1.getkey()`. At this point, the event queue is already empty (this may happen vice versa, of course).

The easy way to fix it is to just pass every event from the main loop to `char1`:

```
while running:
    mainwin.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        char1.getkey(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    char1.animandmove()
    pygame.display.update()
```

and handle them in `getkey`:

```
def getkey(self, event):
    if event.type == ...
        ...
```

There are several other issues with your code but that's out of scope of this question/answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, seems to be working now. Can I DM you later to talk about the other errors in my code?